# How to access a file from a different war which is in the same ear on a Java EE Server (JBoss)?

Tags: java, file-io, jboss, java-ee-6

So following problem:
We have a load balancer with n servers behind it. On each server there is a PDF project (war) installed in ear together with a pdf-builder project in the same earfile (different war).
I now want to read a pdf from the other war.

The problem is: I don't know the IP address of the server I'm running on and using the dns lookup I might end on the different server through the loadbalancer. Furthermore there might be problems with the access / security constraints since the server itself is not a valid user who has rights to make accesses to the pdf file locations of the pdf war project.

Is there a way to obtain something like getResourceAsStream() which works across different modules / war files within an ear?

Comment: Do I understand well the "pdf-builder" project generates some/many PDFs directly inside a deployed exploded WAR directory ?

Comment: The pdf project is basically just a collection of static pdf documents. You have e.g. WEB-INF/pdfs/a.pdf

Comment: Isn't it easier to use a storage shared across nodes (NFS, CIFS...) with a configurable path ?

Comment: Why do you want a solution in pure java when conventional methods serves the purpose like @YvesMartin suggested ?

Comment: @YvesMartin: It certainly would be easier - if it was a small company where you one does not have to file a request for each fart which comes out of ones arse.

Comment: OK I think Teg has a good idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can move the .PDFs to a separate jar (ie pdf-builder.jar) and put it into the .EAR
In the manifest of your .WAR (`META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`) put this line:

```
Class-Path: pdf-builder.jar
```

Now you can load the .PDFs using your class loader. This is J2EE compliant.

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide absolute path to the file in order to access a resource which is not in current class path.

you can call

```
serverletContext.getRealpath("/");
```

will give the the path till the server node (context). From there you can navigate to the file.

One more way is, Jboss uses (or set) several environment variables while it bootstraps. You can use those properties in order to get the current node (like 'default'). Following two properties will give you the absolute path to current server node.

```
System.getProperty("jboss.server.base.dir") + File.separator + System.getProperty("jboss.server.name");
```

(Please use `System.getenv('varname')` if getProperty don't work). From there you can navigate. 
[Here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossProperties) is the complete list of system varibles that jboss uses.

Comment: System.getenv is not relevant. All configuration entries you mention are Java system properties, either set on command line with -D or registered by JBoss code itself

Comment: If the WAR is not exploded, it will necessary to unzip to get the PDF file. JBoss already unzipped deployment archives in its temp directory but there is no luck to guess in which directory a WAR may be.

Comment: Spring reads application context xmls which are in jar (a zip) by using `ZipInputStream`. I think we can read files from a zip by adding `!` (like, path\xxxx.war!\xxx.pdf) to the path.

Comment: The problem is that only WEB-INF/lib/*.jar content and WEB-INF/classes are accessible through ClassLoader and you will face ClassLoader isolation in JBoss implementation - even if you can hack JBoss specific implementation of UnifiedClassLoader. So you will have to build the WAR file path and unzip the content in memory... Not really reliable and not really efficient.

Comment: You can add external jars (they must be inside the .ear) using the manifest Class-Path attribute

Comment: so do I understand correctly, that in this case we have to unzip the ear file, which is, caused by the size of the pdf project, bigger than 150 mb?

Comment: If you use the manifest you dont need to unzip the ear, usually is better to not use file system paths in a j2ee environment.

Answer (score 3):

WARs are intended to be isolated from each other. They can see "up" into the application class loader (EAR level) but cannot access a peer's class loader. So while there may be a way to get it to work on your particular application server, doing so isn't advisable. If someone on the operations team changes deployment options down the line, they may not be aware that you're relying on that mechanism and would break the application in a (possibly) cryptic kind of manner.

Attempting to access a peer class loader like that violates Java EE (if not the letter of the spec, at least the spirit of it).

If you can't put static content on a separate server for access, at least put the static PDFs into a JAR (as been suggested by others) and deploy into the EAR. When do you that, don't forget to add the JAR entry to the manifest file of the declaring WAR (else it won't load the JAR into the application class loader).

Comment: when I put the jar into the server/lib folder i'll get access to it using the classloader as well I guess?

Answer (score 2):

1. Change the `.war` to `.jar` (`.ear`?) if deployment is not too often. For instance in the server lib directory if you do a daily restart.
2. Do not deploy a war, but upload the files to a fixed directory i.e. with **rsync**. *This has my preference.*
3. Do as @Rp- said, possibly unzipping.

Answer (score 0):

I know I have not enough experience to answer such a question like this , so , all I can think of in a very , very rough sketch is setting each .war as a diferent Spring Context and then load it dynamically by setting the aprropiate mapping inside Springs MVC Framework.

[Dynamically Loading Spring Contexts at Runtime](http://www.crazymcphee.net/x/2010/04/29/dynamically-loading-spring-contexts-from-the-classpath-at-runtime/)

[Loading Spring Resources as Dependent Jars](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?105580-Spring-Resources-loading-in-dependant-jars)

[Web resources - Chapter 9 - Spring Reference](http://static.springsource.org/osgi/docs/1.2.x/reference/html/web.html)